# NSDate zero out seconds without rounding up

Tags: objective-c, ios4, nsdate

I would like to know if anyone can help me with my method. I have the following method, which will zero out the seconds value of a NSDate object:

```
- (NSDate *)dateWithZeroSeconds:(NSDate *)date {
    NSTimeInterval time = round([date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] / 60.0) * 60.0;
    return  [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:time];
}
```

The problem is when passed a date such as:

```
2011-03-16 18:21:43 +0000
```

it returns:

```
2011-03-16 18:22:00 +0000
```

I do not want this rounding to occur, as it is a user who is actually specifying the date, so it needs to be exact to the minute they request.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use floor instead of round:

```
- (NSDate *)dateWithZeroSeconds:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSTimeInterval time = floor([date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] / 60.0) * 60.0;
    return  [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:time];
}
```

Comment: +1 That may be less work than bothering with NSDateComponents. It wouldn't work if you wanted to zero out the minutes or hours instead of seconds, but it should be okay here since seconds is the basic unit of a NSDate.

Comment: @DarcyRayner: Cocoa's API is based on NTP so none of the built-in APIs account for leap seconds anyway.

Answer (score 24):

Use NSCalendar and NSDateComponents to get the parts of the date. Set the seconds component to 0, then create a new date from that NSDateComponents.

Comment: Not very helpful when we still have to end up searching for the code to do that.

Comment: @WilliamT. An answer need not provide code snippets for you to cut and paste in order to be helpful. Knowing the right approach, a competent Objective-C programmer would *write* the necessary code rather than search for it.

Answer (score 6):

To be complete, here is the code referenced to iOS SDK 8.1 using NSCalendar and NSDateComponents.

```
+ (NSDate *)truncateSecondsForDate:(NSDate *)fromDate;
{
     NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
     NSCalendarUnit unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitEra | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth |  NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute;
     NSDateComponents *fromDateComponents = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:fromDate ];
     return [gregorian dateFromComponents:fromDateComponents];
}
```

Note that as of iOS 8 the calendar unit names have changed.

Comment: Thanks this helps me!

Answer (score 2):

Swift 2.2 version of @Neil answer:

```
func truncateSecondsForDate(fromDate: NSDate) -> NSDate {

    let calendar : NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let unitFlags : NSCalendarUnit = [.Era , .Year , .Month , .Day , .Hour , .Minute]
    let fromDateComponents: NSDateComponents = calendar.components(unitFlags, fromDate: fromDate)

    return calendar.dateFromComponents(fromDateComponents)!

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the start of any time unit — such as an minute — with `rangeOfUnit:startDate:interval:forDate:`

```
NSDate *startOfMinuteDate;
[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitMinute
                                startDate:&startOfMinuteDate 
                                 interval:NULL 
                                  forDate:originalDate];
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 version :

```
func truncateSecondsForDate(fromDate: Date) -> Date {

    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let fromDateComponents: DateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.era , .year , .month , .day , .hour , .minute], from: fromDate as Date) as DateComponents

    return calendar.date(from: fromDateComponents as DateComponents)! as Date
}
```